# Symfony- How can i store a simple data into MySQL database using JQuery/AJAX??

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

i am trying to store a simple data (file title) in a div element into Mysql db.. can any one point out the error in my code? 
here's my scipt:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#store-button" ).click(function() {
        var title = $( "#pdf-title" ).text();
        storeData(title);
    });

});


function storeData(title)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{ path('store') }}',
        data: { title: title } ,

        success: function (data) {
            // this is executed when ajax call finished well
            alert('content of the executed page: ' + data);
        },
        error:function(error){
            alert('Error: data couldnt be created');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

and here's my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/store", name="store")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function storeAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = new Data();
    $data->setFileName($request->request->get("title"));
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();

}
```

Comment: What response/error do you get when execute it?

Comment: the problem is i don't get any error upon clicking the submit button!! but when i check my DB.. nothing is stored.

Comment: Try this in the controller: `$title = $request->request->get("title") ; ` `var_dump($title);`  did you see the `$title` value?

Comment: Remember that all browsers have developer mode, which can give you a little more insight into the request internals. Also, PHP has a page debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

json data passed through jquery normally needs to be stringified, So you can try to do this:

```
function storeData(title)
{
    var data = {title: title};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{ path('store') }}',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),

        success: function (data) {
            // this is executed when ajax call finished well
            alert('content of the executed page: ' + data);
        },
        error:function(error){
            alert('Error: data couldnt be created');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks 4u guys.. did figure out the origin of the problem, mistyping the id as pdf_title instead of pdf-title cause this inconvenience!! again sorry and thanks for your help!!